# ServiceStack breaks when hosted in AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, servicestack

Currently experiencing an issue with ServiceStack where it will not run in AWS api gateway past version 5.8 with request logging turned on.  If I turn request logging off everything is fine.

Fixed as of version 5.10.3, thanks mythz!

Answer (score 0):

By default ServiceStack infers the BaseUrl from the incoming Request URL, but you can configure it to use a specific external facing URL with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
#if !DEBUG
    WebHostUrl = "https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev"
#endif
});
```

Alternatively you can override `GetBaseUrl(IRequest)` in your AppHost to change the default runtime behavior for which BaseUrl to use at runtime.

Comment: So I tried doing this, actually went as far as the following to make sure it was being set:

`
           SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                AddRedirectParamsToQueryString = true,
                DebugMode = AppSettings.Get(nameof(HostConfig.DebugMode), false),
                WebHostUrl = "https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev"
            });
`

Still getting the exact same behavior.  Drops the /dev on the request to favicon.  Wish this would work as we really want to update.

Comment: @MikeGilge Are you referring to the default [favicon.ico request that browsers automatically request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) that's always made at the `/favicon.ico` of a domain? Or an actual missing resources in the /swagger-ui page? Can you update your answer to include the raw HTTP Request/Response headers of the page with the issue and the HTML fragment that's causing it (the AWS API Gateway might be doing some URL rewriting).

Comment: I updated my original post with additional details.  Would really like to get this fixed.

Comment: @MikeGilge If this is only concerning the failed `/favicon.ico` request please read my previous comment + link. Browsers have been making `/favicon.ico` requests since last millennia, you'd either need to put a `/favicon.ico` at the root of your App or you can [override the /swagger-ui/index.html](https://docs.servicestack.net/swagger-api#overriding-swaggers-embedded-resources) with a custom version [defining its own favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use) or if you're still using old `SwaggerApiFeature` [switch to OpenApiFeature](https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi).

Comment: The problem is with the request logging turned on it totally breaks and I get a white screen of death, disabling that commented line makes it work.  There are no exceptions and zero indication of what is wrong besides that stupid favicon.  Highly suspect that if the favicon is fixed it still would die on the next thing.  I was hoping you might have an idea why it breaks going from version 5.8 to anything newer as it was working fine before this BUG was introduced.

Comment: @MikeGilge The `403 Forbidden` response to `/favicon.ico` is being returned by an AWS Gateway (likely CloudFront) the request doesn't reach ServiceStack. Not clear what bug you're referring to `/favicon.ico` requests are not new, it would always have been requested - it's going to be a red herring to any other other issues you're having, which is not clear from what's provided. If you're saying the `/swagger-ui` is returning a "white screen of death"? then I'd look for any other failed Network requests or JS Errors in Chrome's Web Inspector.

Comment: @MikeGilge It's still not clear what "white screen of death" means or even what the actual issue is, but it sounds like the issue is with the `DynamoRequestLogger` which I'm unfamiliar with. Does it still occur if you comment `//RequestLogger = ...`  so it uses the default in memory request logger?

Comment: I just tried it with RequestLogger commented and EnableRequestBodyTracking uncommented and I still get the empty screen instead of a Swagger page.  I get no errors in any of my other logs, nor in the cloudwatch logs for the lambda that is hosting the api.  The only thing I get is the stupid favicon thing which i suspect is meaningless.

Comment: @MikeGilge If the issue with logging the Request Body can you [enable Request Buffering](https://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#buffering-the-request-and-response-streams) if you haven't already.

Comment: Enabled Request Buffering and no change in behavior.

Comment: @MikeGilge If you have buffering enabled can't think of anything else. `EnableRequestBodyTracking` just calls `IRequest.GetRawBody()` which you can try calling in a GlobalRequestFilter wrapped in a try/catch to see if you can catch any Exceptions thrown. Can you repro this issue locally or does it only occur behind an AWS Gateway?

Comment: Added a GlobalRequestFilter and wrapped it as you suggested.  Throwing a null reference exception in HttpResponseExtensions line # 127.  Incidentally enabling Request Buffering also breaks in API Gateway (with request logging off).

Comment: @MikeGilge Ok should be helpful, can you update your question with the full Exception StackTrace.

Comment: done also this does not happen locally only out in AWS.

Comment: Appears this issue is due to a [missing IHttpBodyControlFeature in the ASP.NET Core App](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v5.8/src/ServiceStack/HttpResponseExtensions.cs#L122-L123) which is unusual, what version of ASP.NET Core is running on AWS? I've added a guard against the NRE in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/6ac4bd1842c170f1569bb5aa1020a37c7bb4017d), will take a while to make it through CI, will let you know when a new version is available on MyGet.

Comment: @MikeGilge FYI this change is available from v5.10.3+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: just tried v5.10.3 and am still getting the same exception/stacktrace as above.

Comment: @MikeGilge The exact same line numbers as well? Something's very off. The only things that could throw an Exception are `HttpContext` or `HttpContext.Features` which should never be null, can you try [inlining this code in a GlobalRequestFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/6ac4bd1842c170f1569bb5aa1020a37c7bb4017d/src/ServiceStack/HttpResponseExtensions.cs#L124-L142) around a try/catch to workout what is causing the NRE.

Comment: I tried doing as you suggested but am not getting any errors, not entirely sure I did just as you asked, I posted my code above.

Comment: @MikeGilge It shouldn’t throw, but you said you got the exact same NRE Exception with the latest v5.10.3 Release on MyGet which should be running this same code, are you sure you’re using the latest v5.10.3 Release? Can you [clear your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#clear-nuget-package-cache) and do a clean restore + build.

Comment: Good call, I did as you suggested and all is good now.  Thanks much for the assist!